# In Place Rebuild a TDE Encrypted SQL Server Instance

Tags: sql-server, encryption, transparent-data-encryption

I have a TDE Encrypted SQL Server machine (with a masterkey, Certs, etc).  I need to rebuild this SQL Server onto new hardware, BUT keep the original SQL Server Name. The new box will be named exactly like the old Box was. This is to avoid a multitude of application and connection changes.

I am going to backup all all encrypted DBs along with logins, jobs, etc. and copy these to the new machine. Then, take the original box offline and bring the new one online (install and configure SQL, etc). Basically I am going to swap the machines.

Has anyone ever need to do something like this?

How do I handle the TDE from the original machine - master key and certs? I need to set up TDE on the new machine which will now has exactly the same name as the original machine did. If I create a new master key using the

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION ...
```

statement on the new machine, will I be able to restore the backed up DBs to my new box using the old Certs from the original machine?